# Subsetting a dataset based on a list

Tags: r, subset

A surveyor submits all of the bird species they captured during a season. I want to subset out their captures so each species is their own dataframe. I can write out the individual species, such as I’ve done in the last line below. But I’d like to be slicker than that, and not have to go through for the entire 300 possible species. Options?

```
Birds <-c()
Birds$Species <-c("REVI","SCTA","REVI","KIWA","BAOR","MAWA","MAWA","BAOR")
Birds <- as.data.frame(Birds)
sp <- unique(Birds$Species)
REVI <- subset(Birds,Species=="REVI")
```

Thanks.

Comment: See `help(split)`, and please provide the desired result given the example data.

Answer (score 1):

As @Richard Scriven points out, you can do this rather easily using `split`. This should work:

```
res<-split(Birds,Birds$Species)
```

We tell R to split the Birds dataframe by the `Species` variable. Then you can access specific species level `data.frames` by simply doing a call such as:

```
res[["BAOR"]]

  Species
5    BAOR
8    BAOR
```

We can see that the result is in fact a `data.frame` by:

```
class(res[["BAOR"]])
[1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: First off, thank you for the help. My ultimate goal is to create one shapefile for each species. Since these are all now packaged together (res), how does that work? In order to keep it simple, How would you write an excel file for each species?    write.xlsx(res,'S:/Bird_data/Species.xlsx'